# How to force ShowModal to open Form on specific monitor?

Tags: delphi, multiple-monitors, delphi-10-seattle

I have two monitors, where the main (left, larger) monitor is `Screen.Monitors[0]` and the secondary (right, smaller) monitor is `Screen.Monitors[1]`.

So in Delphi 10 Seattle I write:

```
var M: Integer;
M := Self.Monitor.MonitorNum; // -> 1 (main app is located on secondary monitor)
aFullScreenForm := TFullScreenForm.Create(SELF);
aFullScreenForm.SetBounds(Screen.Monitors[M].Left, Screen.Monitors[M].Top, Screen.Monitors[M].Width, Screen.Monitors[M].Height);
aFullScreenForm.ShowModal;
aFullScreenForm.Free;
```

However, the form `aFullScreenForm` is always shown full-screen on the main monitor instead of the secondary monitor!

So how can I force the form `aFullScreenForm` to open on the secondary monitor (or on the same monitor where the main application form is located)?

Comment: No problem with XE2. Check DefaultMonitor of full screen form not to be dmPrimary...

Comment: `aFullScreenForm.DefaultMonitor` currently is `dmActiveForm`. So when main form is on secondary monitor, `aFullScreenForm` should also be on secondary monitor. Unfortunately it is not.

Comment: Even when `aFullScreenForm.DefaultMonitor` is `dmMainForm`.

Comment: No, I don't create it at startup. I create it when I need it.

Comment: I've now tried to trace where FullScreenForm changes the monitor: Before `ShowModal` it is still on the secondary monitor (where it should be), after `ShowModal` it is on the primary monitor. So I started to trace it in the FullScreenForm's event-handlers: In `FormShow` the FullScreenForm is still on the secondary monitor, and then in `FormActivate` it is on the PRIMARY monitor!! So what is happening between `FormShow` and `FormActivate` which makes FullScreenForm change its position?

Comment: Aaaahhhh -- I've found the culprit! `FullScreenForm.Align` was `alClient` from designtime, so I changed it to `alNone` at designtime, which solved the problem! Evidently, when `FullScreenForm.Align` is `alClient` then the form always snaps to the primary monitor. Can somebody confirm this? I've made the confirmation test: In `FormActivate` the FullScreen form was still on secondary monitor, then `Sleep(1000)`, then `FullScreenForm.Align := alClient`, then the form snapped to the primary monitor!

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem. (Delphi 10.2 / Tokyo)

After not seeing a fix here I did my own debugging and discovered the following:

Before showing my modal form (having just created it in code), its `DefaultMonitor` property was set to `TDefaultMonitor.dmActiveForm`. By changing it to **dmDestop**:

`F.DefaultMonitor := TDefaultMonitor.dmDesktop;`

all works as desired.

Note: I calculate its position relative to (centered on) a form I want to display it over. This (underneath) form has its `Left` and `Top` values correctly set regardless of which monitor it's on.

Answer (score -1):

To Show the Modal Form in same Screen of Main Form

Modal Form properties

```
Position := poOwnerFormCenter;
Align := alNone;
//if You wanna the modal form on max size
WindowState := wsMaximized;
```

on Form Modal OnActivate Event

```
Left := mainForm.Left;
Top := mainForm.Top;
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.